# how can i save the avg to a text file and be printed out

Tags: java

how wold i take the avg of the fallowing program and save the out come to a text file to be printed out

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class freethrowpercent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double freethrowsmade = 1;
        double freethrowsmissed = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter 1 if freethorw is made enter 0 for freethrows missed");
        freethrowsmade = input.nextDouble() + 1;
        freethrowsmissed = input.nextDouble() + 0;
        double answer = freethrowsmade / 2 * 100;
        System.out.println("percent is" + answer);
    }
```

if that is possable

Comment: Are you familiar with [`java.io` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html)?

Comment: You want to write "percent is"+answer into a file?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with the zero and one. What should be the input? What should be the output? What do you get? And do you know how to calculate a player's actual freethrow percentage?

Comment: or do you want a *variable* number of throws?

Comment: i want to take what the program finds and make it so the it will be saved to a text file

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest getting familiar with [basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) in Java.

If your intention was to write `answer` to a file, here's one way to do it:

```
FileWriter writer = null;
try {
    String str = Double.toString(answer);
    File f = new File("/path/to/file.txt");
    writer = new FileWriter(f);
    writer.write(str);
} catch (IOException ex) {

} finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so should i just copy an paste that

Comment: You'd have to make sure you have your imports in order, too. Import `java.io.File`, `java.io.FileWriter`, and `java.io.IOException`. You'd want to use a path to a real file. I highly suggest making sure you understand what this code is doing in addition to doing a little reading on `java.io`.

Comment: can you write the code for me the text files name is freethorw